# How to convert topic index to topic words in LDA

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lda

How to get a vocabArray out of an LDA model (org.apache.spark.ml.clustering.LDA) . I am just getting vocabSize which returns number of words scanned.

Ideally I need the array of actual words from the model and then based on termindices I want to see the words inside a bucket.

I need to do this in scala. Any suggestion will be helpful.

Things I have tried till now, my topicIndices is a dataframe

```
topicIndices: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [topic: int, termIndices: array<int>, termWeights: array<double>]
```

I am trying to fetch the topics like this

```
val topics = topicIndices.map { case (terms, termWeights) =>
      terms.zip(termWeights).map { case (term, weight) => (vocabArray(term.toInt), weight) }
    }
```

But it throws the following error

```
> 

val topics = topicIndices.map { case (terms, termWeights) =>
      terms.zip(termWeights).map { case (term, weight) => (vocabArray(term.toInt), weight) }
    } <console>:96: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;  found   : (T1, T2)  required: org.apache.spark.sql.Row
       val topics = topicIndices.map { case (terms, termWeights) =>
                                            ^ <console>:97: error: not found: value terms
             terms.zip(termWeights).map { case (term, weight) => (vocabArray(term.toInt), weight) }
             ^
```

Comment: You are using the spark-shell ?

Comment: I am using databricks notebook for this experiment.

Comment: The issue is in old mllib LDA describetopics use to return Array over topics. Each topic was (term indices, term weights in topic). In ml LDA describetopics is returning [topic: int, termIndices: array<int>, termWeights: array<double>] . Earlier it was easy to map the key value pair, any ideas how we should be mapping in this newer one?

Answer (score 2):

Got the issue solved. Here is the missing piece. Once you get the df from describetopics here is the code that can help to get the corresponding words. (Note: This code is working for ml library for LDA )

```
val topicDF = model.describeTopics(maxTermsPerTopic = 10)
for ((row) <- topicDF) {
        val topicNumber = row.get(0)
        val topicTerms  = row.get(1)
        println ("Topic: "+ topicNumber)
}

import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray

val vocab = vectorizer.vocabulary

for ((row) <- topicDF) {
    val topicNumber = row.get(0)
    //val terms = row.get(1)
    val terms:WrappedArray[Int] = row.get(1).asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[Int]]
    for ((termIdx) <- 0 until 4) {
        println("Topic:" + topicNumber + " Word:" + vocab(termIdx))
    }
}

topicDF.printSchema
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

topicDF.collect().foreach { r => 
                r match {
                        case _: Row => ("Topic:" + r)
                        case unknow => println("Something Else")
        }
}

topicDF.collect().foreach { r => {
                        println("Topic:" + r(0))
                        val terms:WrappedArray[Int] = r(1).asInstanceOf[WrappedArray[Int]]
                        terms.foreach {
                                t => {
                                        println("Term:" + vocab(t))
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
```